# Amplitude Phase Shift Keying: Voltage Level Determination at Receiver

Tags: digital-communications, propagation

I am learning about communications via some of the coursework available [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/16-36-communication-systems-engineering-spring-2009/pages/lecture-notes/). In lecture 6 of the coursework, the author introduces the concept of Amplitude Shift Keying, and I have a question which is not addressed in the notes.

I am considering how ASK could be used for transmission and reception through EM waves with a variably located receiver. If I have two receivers, one of which is at a distance \$ d_1 \$ from the receiver and the other is at a distance \$ d_2 = 2d_1 \$ from the receiver, then assuming everything else is constant, the signal power received at the second receiver will be -6dB compared to the power received at the first receiver according to the Friis Transmission equation (For a lossless medium).

My question is, how is this accounted for in the ASK shift keying? Based on my analysis above, if the transmitter defines the following four levels and corresponding codes

-3v = 00, -1v = 01, 1v = 10, 3v = 11

Then after transmission, these codes will vary based on the receiver's distance from the transmitter. This is if, after accounting for propagation, the voltage levels at receiver one are

-1v = 00, -0.33v = 01, 0.33v = 10, 1v = 11

Then since receiver two is at double the distance, the levels for receiver two would be

-0.5v = 00, -0.17v = 01, 0.15v = 10, 0.5v = 11

Is there anything that can be done to account for the distance between transmitter and receiver for ASK, especially when the distance is not known in advance?

Edit: I guess before transmission, it would be possible to introduce a known "preamble" of the message. This preamble could include a bit sent to define each of the possible voltage levels. For example, if the receiver knew all messages start was 00 01 10 11, it could determine what voltage level each symbol is at. This is one potential way to address the problem, but are there others?

Comment: Usually, receivers have an Automatic Gain Control (AGC) algorithm which detects the received signal power and ensures that the ADC at the end of the RF front-end receives the correct voltage swing. In your case, simplistically the gain before the ADC will be doubled for the distant receiver so that the correct levels are detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *amplitude detector* having negative output voltage? Seems very odd - I can't imagine an amplitude below zero. No signal (just noise) should yield a positive (but small) amplitude. A proper amplitude detector gives a scalar output above zero.

---

- The OP's suggestion for normalizing the receiver's detector output is commonly used. A known modulation preamble might include a reference level - sometimes full amplitude. Many infra-red *remotes* include a preamble.
- Run-length-limited coding might be an alternative, where at least one *full-amplitude* modulation symbol occurs in every RLL sequence.
- A portion of the modulation range might be devoted to setting a reference level. This might be done by using one symbol to only represent a reference level - its place in the symbol stream is regular - say every tenth symbol. NTSC video modulation is an example where H-sync and V-sync have a devoted amplitude range where no video is present.
- Every symbol might include a fraction at full amplitude, regardless of symbol's content. For example, WWVB transmits three symbols, each having a portion at full amplitude, from: [An Enhanced Broadcast Format and Multi-Mode Receiver.pdf](https://s2.smu.edu/%7Eyliang/publications/WWVB%20Time%20Signal%20Broadcast%20%20-%20An%20Enhanced%20Broadcast%20Format%20and%20Multi-Mode%20Receiver.pdf):
  [image: WWVB legacy AM 3-symbol modulation]

Answer (score 1):

Amplitude Shift Keying, to use your example, assigns 4 different levels to achieve 2 bits of data per transmission cycle. While it is true that the actual receive levels will decrease as the range increases, there will still be 4 distinct levels. Thus, the 2 bits can still be decoded. As the distance gets larger, the difference in levels will get harder to correctly detect due to noise both received over the air and internally generated in the receiver. Thus the bit error rate will increase as the range increases. This is true for any form of data transmission, not just ASK.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there anything that can be done to account for the distance between
> transmitter and receiver for ASK, especially when the distance is not
> known in advance?*

The two extreme amplitude bits in the data need to be "exercised" quite often so that the receiver can position its detection circuit to figure out where all four levels are. Once that is established, the receiver will keep track of the actual amplitudes even if they gradually vary with time.

It's the same problem with two levels (such as simple OOK). Adding "n" more levels just means you need "n" times more complexity in terms of comparators etc..